# How do I disable the OSX startup sound?

Tags: mac-osx, mac, startup

Is it possible to disable the start up sound on my MacBook Pro running OSX 10.5.6? I find it can be disturbing to others at certain times.

Comment: well, now I can ask this question at SuperUser.com!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go;
[Debonging link](http://www.curby.net/filelib/DebongIntel/)

Comment: in case the link ever changes, he is referring to "DebongIntel.dmg" by developer Michael Lee